# Linkedin token not valid

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api

Here is a strange thing I am fighting against.

First of all I am using this [simple-linkedinphp](https://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/) lib to perform API calls from my php backend.
I got a user access token from our IOS app which has the following structure:
`{"access_token":"lettersAndSymbols","expires_in":5183999}`
I store it in a variable called `$token`.
Then I try to get the user's profile with this token like this:

```
$linkedin = new \LinkedIn($this->linkedin_config);
$linkedin->setResponseFormat($linkedin::_RESPONSE_JSON);
$linkedin->setTokenAccess(array('oauth_token' => $token["access_token"], 'oauth_token_secret' => ""));
$linkedinUserJson = $linkedin->profile("~");
```

Then I get the response with error:

```
array(5) {
  ["linkedin"]=>
  string(358) "{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "[unauthorized]. The token used in the OAuth request is not valid. sameLettersAndSymbols",
  "requestId": "74T6SY6ML6",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1376043937705
}
```

But when I try to open an api url in a browser with the same LettersAndSymbols like `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=LettersAndSymbols`, I get the correct response with user object.

How can that be? Am I doing something wrong with the API lib?

Comment: Do you already have any solutions about this? Same problem here!

Comment: Unfortunately no. I gave up with that lib.

Answer (score 2):

I can see a problem in this line

$linkedin->setTokenAccess(array('oauth_token' => $token["access_token"], 'oauth_token_secret' => ""));

your must provide a secret to set the token access.

I found a nice example about Linkedin Integration, wich I like to share with you, I tested and it works just fine.

[How to Integrate login with LinkedIn oAuth in PHP](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-login-with-linkedin-oauth-in-php_185.html)